# How to prompt the user again to enter the right ID if invalid and stops the loop when entered the right ID

Tags: java, loops

I've been trying to validate the ID input. When ID is invalid, it should prompt the user to enter it again. However, when the ID is correct that seems to work well. Although the invalid validation takes me to infinite loop or it stops right there when entered.

```
public class validate  {
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid_len;
        int letter = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int num_id = 0;
        char chars;
        String temp_dog_id = "";
        System.out.print("Enter the Dog ID ");
        temp_dog_id = in.nextLine();
        num_id = temp_dog_id.length();
        valid_len = (num_id >= 5) ? true : false;

        String dog_id = temp_dog_id;

        for (int i = 0; i< num_id; i++)
        {
            chars = temp_dog_id.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(chars) && Character.isUpperCase(chars))
            {
                letter = dog_id.indexOf(chars, 1);
            }
            if (Character.isDigit(chars))
            {
                digit++;
            }
        }
        while((num_id < 5 && valid_len))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the Dog ID ");
            temp_dog_id = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Invalid. Enter the Id again. An example of ID of Dog would be eg. 1M434");
            k++;
        }
        if ((letter == 1) && valid_len)
        {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of `while (true) {   }` loops. Prompt the user for input like it's the first time asking, then inside the while (true) loop use if else to check if the id is valid. In the if statement that executes if the ID is valid put `break;`, then in the else do something like `System.out.println("Wrong ID, please enter it again: ");` and then overwrite the ID scanning for it again.

Doing it like that will have this result:

1. First you ask for the id, if the id is valid the program doesn't tell you anything about you having committed a mistake.
2. If the id is wrong it tells you and it asks you to enter it again, if you enter it right, it will exit and take it as correct like it's the first time you enter it.
3. If it's still incorrect it will do what is described at the beginning of point 2. Every time you enter it wrong it will do the same thing, once it's right it will stop.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the suggestion and use the flag value. It took me awhile, but I've got it now :)

Comment: @NicoRobin no problem, happy to hear you fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

First, I don't think you need to specify `== true`, that's implied in the `while` loop.

Second, think of the order this is in. If they get the id wrong once then correct after that, how will the code know if it's right? At the moment it just exits.

Comment: Thank you! My ordering was wrong and that also gave me idea to rearrange the last part. It's working now :)